# What wrong with the scaling?

Tags: transforms

First of all, sorry for this newbie question. I selected the face of a cube and scale, this is what I get
[image]

However, after pressing tab to go into object mode, select the whole unit, follow by shift-D and duplicate the same object, tab again to enter edit mode, select the same face on the duplicated object and scale, I got the result as below.
[image]

Been searching youtube for answer but not sure where to look for the solution and why this occur. Tried the pivot option but still cannot get the result.

Comment: So, with the face selected, you pressed Shift+D, which duplicated the face. Then, you scaled it? If so, then nothing's wrong, you're scaling the extra face you've created, which is not "linked" to the rest of the geometry. What were you trying to achieve? What did you expect to see?

Comment: My bad, edited my question. I want the surface scaling to occur like the original object.

Comment: It just looks like you have a duplicated face. Delete it, select the face beneath it and sclae like you want.

Comment: Realized where my mistake. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution just like what community mentioned. I made a mistake shift d to duplicate the face and since that not I want, I right click to cancel it(without notice the duplicated face still on top of original object) so whole duplicated object in object mode have an extra face duplicated.